# What is the syntax to return a user defined string in a left outer join?

Tags: sql, syntax, firebird

I have hit a mental blind spot: - in spite of RTFM and other material I can't see this.

If I have a LEFT OUTER JOIN, what syntax is used to return a column for the right table if it exists, or a user defined string if it does not exist?

```
user defined string = "My string"

Table 1
id | text
-----------
1  | bloop
2  | grrrr

Table 2
id | flange
-----------
2  | whiz

Desired result
id | text  | flange
-------------------
1  | bloop | My string
2  | grrrr | whiz
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The COALESCE function in Firebird 1.5 and higher can convert NULL to most anything else. This enables you to perform an on-the-fly conversion and use the result in your further processing, without the need for “if (MyExpression is null) then” or similar constructions.

see [Converting to and from NULL](http://www.firebirdsql.org/manual/nullguide-conversions.html)

e.g.

```
SELECT id,text,COALESCE(flange,'MY string') as flange from ...
```

Comment: Reference particularly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Table1.id,
       ISNULL(Table2.flange, 'UserDefinedString') as flange
FROM 
     Table1

LEFT JOIN Table2
ON Table1.id = Table2.id
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Table1.id,
       COALESCE(Table2.flange, 'UserDefinedString') as flange
FROM 
     Table1

LEFT JOIN Table2
ON Table1.id = Table2.id
```